# svndumpfilter for subversion > 1.7

Tags: linux, svn, svnadmin, svndumpfilter

I got the dump file of my repository from [xp-dev](http://xp-dev.com) using their `import & export` > `Download Repository Dump File`
Then I tried to delete some file from path from all revisions with `svndumpformat`:

```
:~/fixingsize$ svndumpfilter exclude trunk/Debug/filetoremove < MYSVN.dump > newMYSVN.dump
Excluding prefixes:
   '/trunk/Debug/filetoremove'

svndumpfilter: E140001: Malformed dumpfile header '?\13'
```

I understood It may be cause of `svndumpfilter` is for `subversion` less than `1.7`.
I tried using [svndumpfilter3](http://furius.ca/pubcode/pub/conf/bin/svndumpfilter3.html#download) and again, without success:

```
:~/fixingsize$ ./svndumpfilter3 --exclude trunk/Debug/filetoremove < MYSVN.dump >     newMYSVN.dump
Excluding prefixes:
   '/trunk/Debug/filetoremove'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./svndumpfilter3", line 917, in <module>
    main()
  File "./svndumpfilter3", line 768, in main
    format, uuid, text = read_dump_header(fr)
  File "./svndumpfilter3", line 459, in read_dump_header
    assert mo_version
AssertionError
```

Does anyone know anything about it?

Comment: You've used `svndumpfilter3` here, I'd suggest avoiding using it. Use `svndumpfilter` tool instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found a solution.
For some reason I think the file I got from the `xp-dev` using their `import & export` > `Download Repository Dump File` wasn't suitable. Or I didn't know what to do with it.
Anyway I did the next thing:

```
svnrdump dump https://xp-dev.com/svn/MYSVN > MYSVN.dump

svndumpfilter exclude trunk/Debug/filetodelete < MYSVN.dump > newMYSVN.dump
```

And it worked.